# Given an array of equal-length strings

Tags: c++

Given an array of equal-length strings, check if it is possible to rearrange the strings in such a way that after the rearrangement the strings at consecutive positions would differ by exactly one character.

Example

For inputArray = ["aba", "bbb", "bab"], the output should be
stringsRearrangement(inputArray) = false.

All rearrangements don't satisfy the description condition.

For inputArray = ["ab", "bb", "aa"], the output should be
stringsRearrangement(inputArray) = true.

Strings can be rearranged in the following way: "aa", "ab", "bb".

THE CODE:

```
    bool stringsRearrangement(std::vector<std::string> v) {
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    int i,j,count=0;
    do {
        for(i=0;i<v.size()-1;i++) {
            count=0; 
            for(j=0;j<v[0].size();j++) 
                if(v[i][j]!=v[i+1][j]) {
                    count++;
                    if(count==2)
                        break;
                }
            if(count!=1) 
                break;

        }
        if(i==v.size()-2 && j==v[0].size()-1 && count==1)
            return true;

    } while(next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));

    return false;
}
```

The code not work for example `inputArray: ["ab", "bb", "aa"]` or `inputArray: ["a", "b", "c"]`,after 4 hours thinking can't find the mistake.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code with a debugger?

Comment: I always debugg in my mind,because it's more efficiant for me :)

Comment: split your function, one for permutation iteration, one to compute the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

Comment: I expected a swap somewhere?  (i.e. re-arrangement)

Comment: Go through each string and compute the hamming distance for the others. If, for each string tested, any are 0 or all are 2 or more then it's not possible, otherwise it is.

Comment: *I always debugg in my mind,because it's more efficiant for me :)* I salute your tenaciousness, but it doesn't appear to be working particularly well in this case. Might I recommend being pragmatic and using all of the tools at your disposal?

Comment: The fact that you've tried to debug this for your mind for four hours but still can't find the bug proves that you can't efficiently debug with your mind. Debuggers are there for a reason. Use it, It will make your life a ton easier.

Comment: Thank you for your advise,i will remember,but i hate debugger and never use it for 2 years,since i am a programmer i always use my mind to debugg,and it never gives me ,what about this problem ,i know that i can find the mistake,but i have a little time,i hoped that you can help me .

Comment: Looks like homework to me...

Answer (score 1):

Split your function by sub-problem to simplify the code:

```
std::size_t hamming_distance(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    std::size_t res = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s1.size(); ++i) {
        res += s1[i] != s2[i];
    }
    return res;
#if 0 // or in C++17
    return std::transform_reduce(
        s1.begin(), s1.end(),
        s2.begin(),
        0u,
        std::not_equal_to<>{},
        std::plus<>{});
#endif
}

bool isAnRearrangement(const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    return std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(),
                              [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2){
                                  return hamming_distance(s1, s2) != 1;   
                              }) == v.end();
}

bool stringsRearrangement(std::vector<std::string> v) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    do {
        if (isAnRearrangement(v)) {
            return true;
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/LnKeFp)

Then you might test each part easily:

- Do you compute correctly `hamming_distance("aba", "bbb")` ?
- Which is the result of  `isAnRearrangement({"aa", "ab", "bb"})` ?
- and so on...

For your code, you break your loop in case of error, and so your condition is to check that the loop ends without break at the end, but value of `i`/`j` would be respectively `v.size()-1` and `v[0].size()`. So with sub function, you would just have `return false;` instead of `break;` and `return true;` instead of your conditional `return true;`.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/PEY1b1)

Comment: the result of isAnRearrangement({"aa", "ab", "bb"}) is True

Comment: @LevonMuradyan: I know that expected result is `true`, and that my implementation returns `true` too. I would just explain that the sub-problem can be tested alone with different input and be debugged alone. so for wrong result with `stringsRearrangement`, you may test when `isAnArrangement` fails and so on.

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42 ,i found the mistake,as you said the value of `i/j` would be respectively `v.size()-1` and `v[0].size()`.But i don't understand why `i` an `j` increase by 1 when in cycle last `i` was `v.size()-2` and `j` was `v[0].size()-1`?

Comment: @LevonMuradyan: Way to thanks is the upvote. There is also one answer to accept if it solves your issue (yours is ok BTW).

Comment: I can't ,my reputation less than 15,so i can't upvote any answer

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i found the mistake. Value of `i/j` would be respectively `v.size()-1` and `v[0].size()`.Below is the correct code that real working,thank you Jarod42

```
bool stringsRearrangement(std::vector<std::string> v) {
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    int i,j,count=0;
    do {
        for(i=0;i<v.size()-1;i++) {
            count=0; 
            for(j=0;j<v[0].size();j++) 
                if(v[i][j]!=v[i+1][j]) {
                    count++;
                    if(count==2)
                        break;
                }
            if(count!=1) 
                break;

        }
        if(i==v.size()-1 && j==v[0].size() && count==1)
            return true;

    } while(next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));

    return false;
}
```

Comment: When i use `break` in `for(i=0;i<v.size()-1;i++)` ,why `i` increase by 1?

Comment: For `int i; for (i = 0; i != 42; ++i) {}` final value of `i` is `42` . the first value for which `i != 42` is `false` and so stop the loop.